# How to merge several Swagger (v. 1.2) JSON files?

Tags: swagger

Having a master JSON file

```
{"swaggerVersion":"1.2",
 "apiVersion":"1.0",
 "apis":[{"path":"/api1"},{"path":"/api2"},{"path":"/api3"},{"path":"/api4"}]}
```

and JSON files for each of the 4 APIs, which working well with the Swagger library each.

But when I tried to place it all into one JSON file like

```
 {"swaggerVersion":"1.2",
  "apiVersion":"1.0",
  "apis":[{<api1 json file contents>},{<api2 json file contents>},{<api3 json file contents>},{<api4 json file contents>}]}
```

it didn't work.

What is proper way to do merge several Swagger v. 1.2 files into a single file?

Comment: What are the contents of each api file? What is the error message that you get?

Comment: More details than "It didn't work" would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Swagger 1.2 Specification](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/1.2.md) you just cannot do that.

The "master" JSON file (as you called it) is the [Resource Listing](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/1.2.md#51-resource-listing) of a Swagger API, which just contains an "inventory of the available resources".

The "apis" property of this JSON document is expected be an array of [Resource Object](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/1.2.md#512-resource-object)s with a specific structure:

```js
{
  "path": "/pets",
  "description": "Operations about pets."
}
```

Quoting the [API Declaration](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/1.2.md#52-api-declaration) section of the spec:

> The API Declaration provides information about an API exposed on a resource.  There should be one file per Resource described. The file MUST be served in the URL described by the path field.

Comment: What about the `Swagger 2.0` spec?

Comment: @Shamoon - Swagger 2.0 is indeed a single file. At the time the question was posted, Swagger 2.0 was not available.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the demo application to view all service documentations at a single location: https://github.com/varghgeorge/microservices-single-swagger

Repo shows how to create a springboot application which will serve as a single place for all your springfox/swagger documentations.

Swagger documentation from different services/locations can be configured in this server using yaml config. Details are on the github location.